# Is the grammar correct? "... liaise with other departments on processes and for documentation"

Tags: grammar, prepositions, syntactic-analysis

"... liaise with other departments on processes and for documentation"

1. Is "on" the correct preposition?
2. Are the words "processes" and "documentation" parallel? Is it correct to conjunct them in a sentence like this one?
3. Is there a better way to say this?

Context: Jane works with other departments to ensure that her department's process and other departments' processes are followed correctly. Jane also needs to obtain the appropriate paperwork from the other departments.

Comment: In every way we look at it, the question is one of rephrasing. The part of sentence shown is acceptable, the preposition *on* is fine, and so on. Voting to close as OT/NARQ.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: Hi "Kris". Could you please suggest a better way of saying this? Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If it is a resume you are writing I would not use the word *liaise* instead of *coordinated* or more commonly understood word. Why?

1) It sounds very pretentious.
2) The word is a back-formation from the *liaison*, and earlier in its life (the early 20th cent.) it was used as a slang by the military folks. 3) Mark Twain said, "When there is a nickel word available don't use a two-bit one."
So it boils down to avoiding being pretentious (very important if you want to get hired) and not risking alienating someone who is screening resumes first.

Is it grammatically correct? Not if you are using as past tense of the verb.

I would write, "Coordinated with other departments and verified the accuracy of process and procedures followed by both."